# I can't understand this type casting

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, type-conversion

I have done type casting with `int` and `char` but not with pointers so I posted this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[4] = { 1, 2, 6, 4 };
    char *p;
    p = (char *)a;   // what does this statement mean?
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    p = p + 1;        
    printf("%d",*p);  // after incrementing it gives 0 why?
}
```

The first call to `printf` gives the first element of the array. And after `p=p+1` it gives `0`. Why?

Comment: just change p = p + 1; to  *p = *p + 1; and it works
because this is working on the values not the pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 6, 4 };
```

declares a as array. `a` at this point of time stores the address of the first element of the array.

```
char *p;
```

declares p as a `pointer` to `character`

```
p = (char *)a;
```

Now since `p` & `a` both stores addresses. So the address stored at `a` (`address` of first element of the array) is assigned to `p`. The typecasting is done as `p` was declared as `char *`

what it does is that, assuming address stored at `a` is say 100 *and assuming that `int` takes 2 bytes and `char` takes 1 bytes in memory*

```
a+1 would return a+size of int(2) = 102
```

and

```
p+1 would return p+size of char(1) = 101
```

and that will explain the output as

A. two bytes stored at `a` contains the first element of the array.

B. one byte stored at `p` is the character representation of the first byte of integer `1`, which is `0`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On most modern 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, an int is a 32-bit numbers, so `sizeof(int) == 4`.  That's not guaranteed, but it's probably the case for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for correction. I just intended to make him understand the concept.

Comment: -1 `a` is an array, not a pointer, don't teach beginners obviously wrong things. There are several valid answers below that describe things much better.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks. Corrected that and I never said my answer was any better than anyone else.

Answer (score 5):

Let's imagine a fairly typical platform in which a byte is eight bits, memory is arranged using little-endian byte ordering, and an `int` represents four bytes in memory.  On this platform, a value of `1` would be laid out like so:

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
^
the first element of 'a'
```

`p` is declared as a pointer to `char` (not `int`) and is initialized to points to the first element of the array `a`.  A `char` on this platform represents one byte.  The `int` value above interpreted as a `char` would look like so:

```
00000001 -------- -------- --------
|      |
 ------
 char is only 8 bits wide
```

So, whether we read one byte or four, i.e., whether we read `*p` or `a[0]`, the value is `1`.  However, when you increment `p`, a pointer to `char`, it now points to the next *char* in memory, which is the next byte:

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000001 00000000 -------- --------
^        ^        ^        ^
p       p+1      p+2      p+3       ...
```

`a[1]` points to the next `int` (`2`), `p[1]` points to the next `char`, which is `0`.

---

On a side note, you've actually stumbled upon a method to determine if a given processor uses little- or big-endian byte order.  If the system were big-endian (most significant byte first) then your first `printf` would have printed 0.  This is because the memory layout would have changed:

```
0000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
^
the first element of 'a'

0000000 -------- -------- --------
^
p
```

If you have more than a single byte arranged in big-endian order which represent the value 1 and you read only the first byte you can use its value (`1` or `0`) to test the endianness of the machine:

```
int n = 1;
if(*(char*)&n == 1)
    // little endian
else
    // big endian
```

Answer (score 2):

To be exact, the first `printf` doesn't give the first element of the array, it gives the first **8 bits** of first element, which just happens to be equal to the first elements numeric value.
The second printf gives the next 8 bits of first element, which is 0 in this case.

**1  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 (32 bits)**

Comment: To be pedantic, it gives the first `CHAR_BIT` bits, not necessarily 8.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of four integers. You try to access them as an "array" of characters. That's what the casting means.

As for the second `printf` printing zero, remember that integers are four bytes while characters are only one. So increasing the pointer `p` will make `p` point to the second byte of the first integer, which is zero. If you had a larger number (i.e. over 255) then the second byte would have a value as well. But note that this only works on Intel-type machines, which are *little endian*, on *big endian* machines both `printf` would print zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an intel like processor the bytes on the stack are stored using the little endian format. In more, probably the type int (on your computer) has size 4 bytes while char is 1 byte long (you can verify this using the c operator 'sizeof'), so the first element of your integer array is:

```
0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

For this reason when you use a char pointer to see the values of your integer array, you proceed forward one bytes at time (not 4) with the obvious result you've obtained.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

a is a pointer to an array of memory.  This memory is probably arranged in little endian twos complement format as a contiguous block of 16 bytes.

When you cast it, you basically just said "okay, I know this is a pointer to an array of ints, but now we're going to reinterpret the data as an array of chars".  char typically is one byte.  So, when you added one to the pointer, you incremented the *place* the pointer pointed to.  Because it is a char array, it advanced one *byte* down the array, which is in the middle of the int, which contains 0.

To clarify, *based on what I assume about your computer's architecture*:

> Little endian numbers (the least significant byte comes first):
>   00000001000000000000000000000000 in binary = 1 in decimal
>   00000010000000000000000000000000 in binary = 2 in decimal
>   00000110000000000000000000000000 in binary = 6 in decimal
>   00000100000000000000000000000000 in binary = 4 in decimal

Your array of ints looks like this:

> 00000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000

The variable "a" points to the first integer, which is 32 bits (i.e., "*a" is `00000001000000000000000000000000`).  If you add one to the variable "a", you increment *the pointer*, so *(a+1) points to the second int `00000010000000000000000000000000`).

Now, you cast the variable "a" to a "char*" pointer.  So, now, the variable "p" points to the same place, but because it is a char pointer, pointers to the first char, which is 8 bits (i.e., "*p" is `00000001`, the first byte of your array).

Finally, when you increment "p", you increment the *pointer*.  Because "p" is a pointer to chars, it advances one *byte*, so "*(p+1)" is `00000000`.